# White screen appears for a split second after splash screen

Tags: ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst

I have made an app with IBM mobileFirst 7.0 (I also use Ionic) and I notice that right after the splash screen and for half a second or so, a white screen appears. I searched the web and some people said that uncommenting

```
autoHideSplash: false,
```

in wlInitOptions and adding this code:

```
var app = angular.module('app.controllers', []);

//manually hide splash screen
app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
      $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                WL.App.hideSplashScreen();
            }, 100);
         });
        })
```

in my controller (I only have 1) would solve the issue. Yet nothing happens. (I also changed the timeout but nothing seems to change)

I want to seee my app right after the splash screen dissappears without the white screen. How can I do that?

UPDATE & SOLUTION:

After reading Idan's answer, I made a few changes that fixed the problem.
First of all in my index.html, I was loading MobileFirst at the end of my `<head>`, after Ionic and all controllers had loaded. I changed that and now in the `<head>` tag I firstly load:

```
<!-- mobileFirst initialization -->
           <script src="js/wlInit.js"></script>
           <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
```

and then I load Ionic and the controllers.

I also changed the timeout of WL.App.hideSplashScreen() in my controller from 100 to 1500.

No white screen appears any longer :D

Comment: Please look here http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bworklight%5D%20splash%20screen%20is%3aquestion

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/white-page-showing-after-splash-screen-before-app-load/2908/9

Comment: i think first you need to clean the project

Comment: @SantoshShinde I've already read your second link ( I describe the steps I made in my question). I don't think I can install cordova splashscreen in my Worklight project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're using the WL.App API, but are you sure you're using it in the right place? This API can be called only *after*  `function wlCommonInit` was called.

So I think you're on the right path. It sounds like you should indeed try to *extend* the duration of the splash screen as something in your app is taking a while to load (hence the white flashing), so by extending the splash screen a little while longer, letting whatever it is to load, and then removing the splash screen could be a possible workaround.

1. Make sure this API is called only after `wlCommonInit` was called
2. Increase the duration some more.

Read more about the API, here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.0/advanced-client-side-development/common-ui-controls/#splashscreen

Comment: I think I am using the Wl.App API after wlcommonInit was called. I will experiment a little bit more to be sure.

Comment: You were right! I made some changes and it is fixed now. Editing my questions to include what I did. Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ng-cloak to hide any white flashes that angular causes.

Comment: Can you please explain this a bit more?

Comment: Here is the link from Angular's Site 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: Yes, I know what ng-cloak does but how would it hide white flashes? Should I use it in on the body tag for example?

Comment: I've used it in the body tag where I had a dynamic list of items from a database. Every time I would add an Item it would cause a white flash due to post-back. To alleviate this I just put the ng-cloak in the body tag where my dynamic table was.

Comment: Very interesting indeed! Thank you for your anwser!