# Ionic 2 , appear white blank screen after splash screen and before main page

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Currently I am developing ionic 2 project for both android and ios.
I saw the white blank screen after splash screen and before main page. This blank page take 9 or 8 sec to finish. I use the following command

```
ionic start CoeTutorial tutorial --v2
ionic resources    
ionic platform add android
ionic run android
```

Why did the white blank screen come out and how to make it faster?

here is my project link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8MgjhwD8M3UTVprWEd1cEk2dW8/view?usp=sharing

need to type

```
npm install
```

after downloading this sample project.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when developing an app for Ionic and using IBM mobileFirst. It would happen because the splash screen would auto-hide itself before mobileFirst or my controllers would load. What I did to fix this:

- I disabled autohide splash screen from my code
- I programmatically hid the splash screen using a timeout
- Made sure that in my index page mobilefirst would load before controllers and Ionic.

You don't describe what framework you are using (worklight, mobileFirst, Phonegap) but you can do something similar to fix this.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41487246/white-screen-appears-for-a-split-second-after-splash-screen)'s the link to my issue on stack overflow.

Good luck!

Comment: @ Dartfrog Imi I remember reading that you should install cordova splash or cordova splashscreen (i cant remember the name exactly) plugin in order to control autohide of splash screen